# trying to install mysql 5.7 in a docker image in ubuntu machine

Tags: docker, mysql

When trying to install mysql 5.7 in docker container, I am getting the following error. I am new to docker and containers.

```
Step 16/23 : RUN apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
  ---> Running in 9624e9df68e7
 Reading package lists...
 Building dependency tree...
 Reading state information...
 Package mysql-server-5.7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source
 However the following packages replace it:
   mariadb-server-10.3
 E: Package 'mysql-server-5.7' has no installation candidate
 Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install mysql-server-5.7' returned a non-zero code: 100
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

My docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget 
RUN wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN apt-get install -y prometheus

RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list' 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y elasticsearch
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb
RUN apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
RUN mkdir -p -v /data/db
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/Github-MICROSERVICE/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 6001
CMD chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql \
&& service mysql start \
&& mysql -ppassword -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ted;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on ted.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800;SET GLOBAL sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';" \
&& service prometheus start \
&& service mongodb start\
&& npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install an old version of Mysql on a new version of Ubuntu:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

At this time the (Aug 2020) `ubuntu:latest` image tag is a synonym for `ubuntu:20.04`.  This will change for every new release of Ubuntu.  The last version of Ubuntu that had Mysql 5.7 was Ubuntu 18.04. See here https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mysql-server-5.7.

You've got a few options:

## Use the official mysql docker image

You might not need to roll your own image at all.  That's not clear from your question.  So you could just run a container with the docker image `mysql:5.7` or even `mysql:latest` (8.0.21).

## Use a newer version of mysql

Simply change your dockerfile to say:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

This will install the latest Mysql version available for the latest Ubuntu version.

## Use an older version of ubuntu

Change your docker file to say:

```
FROM ubuntu:1804
```